# How to validate a code written for solution of 1D heat conduction problem in a line.

Tags: thermodynamics, diffusion, models

Consider the following conceptual model of heat conduction in a bar. [image] There is a heat source at left side and heat is observed at point Ho after a distance L from the source. If we consider only heat transfer through conduction then this problem can be modeled by diffusion/heat conduction equation. $$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = D \frac{\partial T}{\partial x^2}$$ If I have developed a new semi-analytical or numerical solution (and eventually code) of this problem, then how can I validate my code?. For simplicity, suppose the source to be sinusoidal. Is there a standard solution for such an ideal case with sine input source, so that I can compare my code and then apply it to real field conditions?

Answer (score 0):

You can partially check it by looking at how your code performs in extreme or limiting cases. For example put in a large value for heat conduction and confirm heat transfers quickly. Or put in a zero value and check heat at various locations. This won't confirm you are getting correct numerical values but it will test that code is working as desired.  To test further, without an official table or something of that sort, maybe try matching it to problems found in textbooks.

Comment: I have developed a code which performs understandably well, as you have mentioned but giving different result to a previously developed code. I am looking for a standard data, to which I can compare my code, because I am not sure if that previous code is itself without errors or not, or may be it is using slightly different assumptions?

Comment: Yea I understand. Thats a difficult situation to be in.  I wish I had a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

The amplitude of the oscillation of temperature should decrease with distance away from the boundary where the temperature is being forced.  This is a well-known solution that can be found in Carslaw and Jaeger, Conduction of Heat in Solids.  If you can match the predicted variation of amplitude with distance, that would be regarded as a validation of your computer model.

Comment: Carslaw provides semi-analytical solutions like for semi-infinite case the solution is [this](https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\begin{align}&space;\begin{split}&space;\Delta&space;h_m&space;&=&space;\sum\limits_{m=1}^p&space;\Delta&space;H_m&space;\{&space;erfc&space;\frac{u}{2&space;\sqrt[]{p-m}}&space;\}&space;\end{split}&space;\end{align}) for which I have written [this](https://gist.github.com/AtrCheema/652a2546fcdf2c87e7465a94282e5df1) MATLAB code. But my code is giving me wrong results so I can not compare my newly suggested method with that of Carslaw. If possible could u spot eror?

Comment: This is not the solution I had in mind.  The solution I had in mind was for the dynamic steady state at long times, in which the temperature approaches $$T=T_0+A(x)\sin{\omega t}+B(x)\cos{\omega t}$$  This solution is given in Transport Phenomena by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot, Chapter 4, Example 4.1-3